# Merging times by closest time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I currently have a large table that has random times(not specific fields) it's a single column that contains all distinct times. I have it as a temp table called **#TopPackageSliceTimes**. I have another shorter table that contains times as well, again only a single column. This temp table is called **#DieJamTimes** I want to merge the times from the #DieJamTimes, to #TopPackageSliceTimes in such a way that the times from #DieJamTimes match with the closest time found in #TopPackageSliceTimes. Assume that there won't be multiple times in #DieJamTimes associated with one time in #TopPackageSliceTimes. The times in #DieJamTimes should fall in different times from #TopPackageSliceTimes. If there is a tie between two times and the gap from the two times from #TopPackageSlicesTimes is more then 5 minutes from #DieJamTimes, then I don't care where it's placed at that point. If by chance they are both within 5 minutes the preference would be to place it to the time that was earlier then the DieJamTime.

---

#### TopPackageSliceTimes:

| TopPackage |
| --- |
| 10:23 |
| 11:20 |
| 11:53 |
| 12:20 |

---

#### DieJamTimes

| DieJam |
| --- |
| 10:21 |
| 11:52 |
| 1:50 |

---

The desired result should look like this:

| TopPackage | DieJam |
| --- | --- |
| 10:23 | 10:21 |
| 11:20 | NULL |
| 11:53 | 11:52 |
| 12:20 | 1:50 |

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) What if there are ties?

Comment: Im using MySQL 2014. If there are ties I want to use the one where the Time2 comes after Time1.

Comment: . . To the best of my knowledge, there is no such thing as MySQL 2014.  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry SQL Server 2014

Comment: So the times in the larger table should be referenced semantically as fields, since that's what they are. If your not entering them as fields you should be. Furthermore, are you only placing 1 time per field? what happens if you have the times, __`10:31`, `10:32`, `10:33` & `10:34`__ ???

Comment: I made some changes that hopefully will explain what I am trying to go for a lot better. My first post was a bit confusing, please take a look again to see if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated.  You can get the closest values for `table1` with ties choosing an arbitrary matching row.  You haven't specified a database, but the idea (using Standard SQL) looks like:

```
select t2.*,
       (select t1.time1
        from time2 t2
        order by abs(t1.time1 - t2.time2)
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as time1
from table2 t2;
```

Then, you need to bring in the `NULL` values:

```
with tt as (
      select t2.*,
             (select t1.time1
              from time2 t2
              order by abs(t1.time1 - t2.time2)
              fetch first 1 row only
             ) as time1
      from table2 t2
     )
select tt.time2, tt.time1
from tt
union all
select t1.time1, null
from time1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from tt where tt.time1 = t1.time1);
```

Comment: Sorry could you give reference to what t1, t2, time1 and time2 are referencing.

Comment: To be even more specific if say my Table1 is called #TopSlices and Table2 is #DieJams.  And #TopSlices has TopSliceTimes as the Time1 and #DieJams has DieJamTimes as the Time2